# Is there an orthogonal matrix Q so that the $Q ^ tAQ = D$ and $Q ^ tBQ$ matrices are diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&-2 \\ -2&5  \end{array}\right) \in
> M_n(\mathbb{C})$$
>
> Let $$B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}-3&6 \\ 6&-10  \end{array}\right) \in
> M_n(\mathbb{C})$$

Is there an orthogonal matrix Q so that the $Q ^ tAQ$ and $Q ^ tBQ$ matrices are diagonal

Comment: Simultaneously diagonalisable matrices always commute, but your $A$ and $B$ do not.

Comment: Hello @user1932595, what do you think about my solution? Notice that all what you need to do is to do one multiplication and to check whether the product is symmetrical ( ..and you have exact theoretical explanation)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $Q ^ tAQ=D_1$ and $Q ^ tBQ=D_2$.

Then $Q ^ tAQQ ^ tBQ=Q ^ tABQ=D_1 D_2$
what means that  $AB=QD_1D_2Q^t$ should be symmetric.

You can check that $AB$ in this case is not symmetric.

Comment: For diagonal matrices $D \ \ $ it holds $ \ \ \ \ QDQ^t=(QDQ^t)^t$

Answer (score 0):

No, since no eigenvector of $A$ is also an eigenvector of $B$.